# Flutter - I get a GlobalKey error when using a NavigatorObserver

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile

I have a method I need to call everytime a new route is pushed/popped in the Navigator stack. Basically, everytime the user goes from a screen to another.

I've read that the best way to do this was by using the NavigatorObserver.
I tried to implement it that way :

```dart
class NavigationObserver extends NavigatorObserver {
  @override
  void didPush(Route route, Route? previousRoute) {
    super.didPush(route, previousRoute);

    NotificationsViewState().updateNotifs(); // "Notifications" page
    NotifScrollContentState().updateNotifs(); // content of the notifications modal
  }
}
```

Using this class, I implemented it in my main MaterialApp :

```dart
MaterialApp(
    navigatorObservers: [NavigationObserver()],
    // etc...
```

This resulted in an error implying that the GlobalKeys might be at cause there :

> A GlobalKey was used multiple times inside one widget's child list.
> The offending GlobalKey was: [GlobalObjectKey_WidgetsAppState#263c0]
> The parent of the widgets with that key was:
> _FocusInheritedScop
> The first child to get instantiated with that key became:
> Navigator-[GlobalObjectKey_WidgetsAppState#263c0]
> The second child that was to be instantiated with that key was:
> _FocusInheritedScope
> A GlobalKey can only be specified on one widget at a time in the widget tree.

I am no Dart expert, so I do struggle to understand how could I fix this issue.
FYI, the only GlobalKeys I'm using in my Flutter app are only to implement AnimatedLists, so I don't think that's related.

Comment: The error you're seeing indicates a GlobalKey is being used by multiple widgets, which isn't allowed in Flutter; each GlobalKey must be unique to one widget. Although your code snippet shows the NavigationObserver implementation, the GlobalKey issue likely lies elsewhere in your application, as NavigationObserver doesn't directly involve GlobalKeys.

Comment: This app has been using the same GlobalKeys ever since, and I never encountered this issue before. It's rather weird that this bug is occuring just now, I'm definitely going to take a deeper look into it.
Thanks for the advice.